# What is the Template tag on GitHub and what does it to?

Tags: github

I stumbled upon an intriguing tag next to a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Efrat19/slack-unread-report) in the same spot you'd see `Archived` or `Private`

It says `Template`

[image: Template Repo]

Can't find anything different about the repository, what does the Tag mean? What makes `Template` repositories different?

#### Update, found the checkbox option under the repo renaming setting

**Template repository**

```
Template repositories let users generate new repositories with the same directory
structure and files. Indicate if User/Repo can be used as a template for
creating other repositories.
```

But it doesn't explain how this is different than just `Fork` or `clone and push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Creating a template repository**

You can make an existing repository a template, so you and others can generate new repositories with the same directory structure and files.

Anyone with admin permissions to a repository can make the repository a template.

from https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-template-repository

Comment: Interesting, But how is this different than `forking` or `cloning and pushing`? It's a lot like forking and detaching the upstream

Comment: @SalimDjerbouh I think one difference is that you can have just one fork of someone else's repository, but you can create several different repositories from someone else's template.